# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - could not initialize proxy - no Session SETTING A PROPERTY

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've just got the following exception error when setting a property of a POJO (spring 2 + Hibernate JPA) + MySQL DB):

```
 org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session at     org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167) at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215) at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190) at com.confloorapp.domain.Floor_$$_javassist_0.setNumberOfEvents(Floor_$$_javassist_0.java) at com.ifloor.services.endpoint.UpdateFloorEventServlet.doGet(UpdateFloorEventServlet.java:59) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723) at ...
```

This is the set:

```
floor.setNumberOfEvents    ((Long)numOfEvents);
```

That is the POJO:

```
@Entity @Table(name="T_FLOOR") public class Floor {
@Id
@Column(name = "FLOOR_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "FLOOR_KEY")
private String floorKey;
@Column(name = "NUMBER_OF_EVENTS")
private Long numberOfEvents;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Long getNumberOfEvents() {
    return numberOfEvents;
}
public void setNumberOfEvents(Long numberOfEvents) {
    this.numberOfEvents = numberOfEvents;
}
public String getFloorKey() {
    return floorKey;
}
public void setFloorKey(String floorKey) {
    this.floorKey = floorKey;
}       
}
```

That is the MYSQL table definition:

mySQL

```
  CREATE TABLE `T_FLOOR` (
  `FLOOR_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FLOOR_KEY` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLOOR_DESC` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOCATION_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMBER_OF_EVENTS` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_EVENT` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATE` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `LATITUDE` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `LONGITUDE` float DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`FLOOR_ID`),
   UNIQUE KEY `FLOOR_ID_UNIQUE` (`FLOOR_ID`),
   KEY `FK_floor_location` (`LOCATION_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_door_location` FOREIGN KEY (`LOCATION_ID`) REFERENCES `T_LOCATION` (`LOCATION_ID`)
```

Comment: Tip: Always make changes to entity objects in the DAO layer where you've the session. Making changes to entity objects elsewhere is going to throw the above exception.

Comment: Well, in the controller is where I made the sets, normally:
Floor floor = floorService.getById (id);
floor.setNumberOfEvents    ((Long)numOfEvents);
floorService.saveOrUpdate (floor);

Comment: You are trying to update a proxy. Try calling session.get() in your dao layer.

Comment: I already get the session in the DAO layer:               @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;